# Declare a pointer with assigned value

Tags: c, linux, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *p = 65; 
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

This throws segmentation fault.

But this:

```
int main()
{
    int *p = 65; 
    printf("%d\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Prints the value.

Can anyone help in understanding this?

What happens when we declare pointer variables with values? (Ex: `int *x = 'A';`)

Comment: C++ wouldn't let you do that assignment in the first place, so the confusion would be avoided.

Comment: _What happens when we declare pointer variables with values ? (Ex: int *x = 'A';)_ It points to the address you assign it. Whether you can then read from/write to that address is the real issue.

Comment: A pointer doesn't hold a value, but a memory address. Whatever you assign to it will be interpreted as an address in memory. In the first case you are **dereferencing** the pointer using the operator `*`, which means peek the value at such address pointed to. Unfortunately `65` is an illegal address. In the second case you simply print the address hold by thepointer.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer, like any other variable, can hold a value, whitch should be a memory address, but you can assign to it whatever value you'd like, so `int *p = 65` (or  `int *x = 'A'`) is valid.

You can also print this value by using `printf("%d\n", p)`, though the specifier is wrong, it should be `%p`.

However when you dereference it, ***i.e.*** `printf("%d\n", *p)` you will try to print the value stored in the address stored in the pointer, in this case the address would be `65`. That is a lottery, it maybe the case that by sheer luck the value you assigned is indeed a valid memory address, and in that case the program will work correctly and print whatever value is stored in the address, otherwise the program exhibits [undefined behavior](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3), for which one of the possible outcomes is a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

The first one dereferences `p` and tries to print it. Issue is that you don't know whether `65` is a valid address to read from/dereference, and neither does the compiler. Apparently in your case, it isn't, so segfault.

The second program prints the address 65. The correct format specifier for this is `%p` however, and if your pointer size is 8 bytes, the address might even get truncated in other cases. Nonetheless, it prints the address 65. Apart from the format specifier being wrong, this is well-defined because it doesn't actually try to dereference the pointer, it just prints the address it is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

```
   65   66     67    68    69    70    71   72    73
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Imagine this is a memory print, and the numbers are their respective addresses. If I ask you "what is at address 68?", you would reply "The letter `d`". Likewise, if I asked "what is at address 70?", you'd say "Nothing".

When you use pointers, this is basically what you are doing: asking the computer what are the contents of an address.

```
int *p;  // now you can ask the computer for address
p = 65;  // hey, computer, I'm gonna ask about the address 65
printf("%c", *p); // the computer access the address, then answers.
```

In the above example, the computer would tell you (via `printf`), that *"the contents at address 65, which you asked me, is the letter `a`"*. From this you can see that a pointer is a "two-way" variable. You set the address it should look for when you dereference it (use the `*p`).

```
int *p;
p = 65;

// is equivalent to
int *p = 65
```

In the above example, you are telling the computer you are interested in the address 65. And when you *dereference* the pointer, you are asking the computer "what is the contents of this address you have?". When you do this, the computer tries to *access* that memory address. **If you do not have permissions or if the address is invalid, you get a segmentation fault**. (By the standard, it's undefined behavior...)

```
int *p;  // now you can ask the computer for address
p = 70;  // hey, computer, I'm gonna ask about the address 70
printf("%d", *p); // the computer access the address, then answers.
```

And in the above example, the computer would reply with "there is nothing at that address".

Answer (score 1):

```
int *p = 65;
```

is not assigning the value `65` to some `int` object that `p` points to; it is treating the value `65` as the *address of another `int` object*; this almost certainly *not* a valid address, which is why you get the segfault when you try to dereference it with `*p`.

When you just print the value stored in `p` itself you're not attempting to dereference anything, which is why it works (although you're using the wrong conversion specifier - use `%p` to print pointer values).

Answer (score 1):

The reason of SEGFAULT is explained in other answers.
However, if you want to create an "initialized" pointer that points to `int` of value 42 you can use a *compound literal*.

```
int *p = &(int){42};
```

It's equivalent of:

```
int some_int = 42;
int *p = &some_int;
```